# Web server on Azure VM

Tags: azure, web, nginx, azure-virtual-machine

I've installed a Windows 2012 R2 VM (free tier) and enabled all ports for external communication (including port 80).

I logged in to my VM and installed nginx webserver (I've also tried to python development server).

I can access the website internally on the VM (using 127.0.0.1 or the internal address of the server 10.1....) but when trying to access it from outside, using the external IP address (which is also the IP address I used in order to login to my server using RDP) I get no response.

Can you please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you create inbound rules for the VM (this isn't a setting inside the vm; you can get to the inbound and outbound rules via the portal or CLI)? Without opening up additional ports this way, you'll only have the RDP port open by default.

Comment: Yes i did create it. I enabled RDP, SSH, HTTP and HTTPS

Comment: Check the interface binding of your nginx server to see if it is allowing external connections.

Comment: I did not find anything says differently. BTW, I did exactly the same on an ubuntu VM and it works... The question is what different on Windows.

Comment: The Windows Firewall is what's different on Windows. Poke a hole for 80/TCP.

Comment: That's right! Thanks! Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @evilSnobu OP suggests posting your comment as an answer, If you have not the time to do this, I will post my reply.

Comment: Feel free to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @evilSnobu points out from his comments, the short answer is to allow the TCP port 80 in the windows firewall on windows VM itself.

Usually, we could login to that Windows VM and run the CMD command `netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off` to disable the windows firewall temporarily. Then we can use [telnet](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-telnet-2626026) tool to check if TCP 80 port can be connected.

When we face the same issue no response outside of Azure VM. we can try one or more of the followings:

- There is an NSG at the subnet level or NIC level as well which is not allowing data through.
- There is a firewall on the VM itself (windows firewall etc.)
- There is nothing listening on that port. It should be listening on 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 when you use `netstat -ano` in the windows CMD.
- The service is not staring when you verify the port listening.
- Outbound traffic with a specific port is denied from your local machines.

Hope this helps.